# Intentando mapear valores en C#

Tags: c#, unity, map

Me gustaría mapear los valores de giro de un giroscopio a un valor 
entre -1 y 1;

```
    _________________
    | -1  | 0   | 1 |
    |---------------|
    | 365 | 180 | 0 |
    +---------------+
```

Lo intento con esta operación

```
  Mathf.Lerp(-1f, 1f, ValorGiroscopio);
```

Pero no lo consigo, ¿alguna idea?

Con Arduino se logra muy fácilmente y me gustaría saber si existe
una función parecida

```
map();
```

Comment: ¿La equivalencia siempre es la misma (365 valor mínimo, 180 valor medio, 0 valor máximo)?

Answer (score 3):

Para crear un método que normalice valores en un rango a otro, podemos fijarnos en [la formula de esta respuesta](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/178629):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si trasladamos esto a un método, nos queda algo similar a esto:

```
static public float Map(float value, float istart, float istop, float ostart, float ostop)
{
    return ostart + (ostop - ostart) * ((value - istart) / (istop - istart));
}
```

Modo de llamarlo:

```
var normalizado = Map(165, 0, 365, 1, -1);
```

donde:

```
value - valor a normalizar
istart - valor minimo posible de entrada
istop - valor máximo de entrada
ostart - valor minimo posible de salida
ostop - valor máximo de salida
```

<sub>El método está copiado tal cual del método `map` de [Processing](https://processing.org/)</sub>